# Trigger to send email notification after attachment deletion

Tags: trigger, attachment

I have this trigger to send an email when an attachment has been deleted.

```
trigger send_email on Attachment (after delete) {
    Attachment del = trigger.new[0];
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    String[] toAddresses = new string[] {'salesforceadmin@mastercontrol.com'};
    mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
    mail.setReplyTo('mstambaugh@mastercontrol.com');
    mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Support');
    mail.setSubject('Attachment Deleted : ' + account.name);
    mail.setPlainTextBody('work please');
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
}
```

but I get this message when I attempt to delete an attachment

send_email: execution of AfterDelete

caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Trigger.send_email: line 2, column 1

I just don't know enough to fix this.. any help? TIA

Answer (score 1):

Delete triggers need to reference `Trigger.old`, not `Trigger.new`. [Here are the docs on the context variables](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm).